# How to run multiple linear regressions with different independent variables and dependent variables adding standardized coefficients in R?

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, lapply, purrr

I'm currently trying to run a loop performing linear regression for multiple independent variables (n = 6) with multiple dependent variables (n=1000).

Here is some example data, with age, sex, and education representing my independent variables of interest and testscore_* being my dependent variables.

```
df = data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006,1007, 1008, 1009,   1010, 1011),
                    age = as.numeric(c('56', '43','59','74','61','62','69','80','40','55','58')),
                    sex = as.numeric(c('0','1','0','0','1','1','0','1','0','1','0')),
                    testscore_1 = as.numeric(c('23','28','30','15','7','18','29','27','14','22','24')),
                    testscore_2 = as.numeric(c('1','3','2','5','8','2','5','6','7','8','2')),
                    testscore_3 = as.numeric(c('18','20','19','15','20','23','19','25','10','14','12')),
                    education =  as.numeric(c('5','4','3','5','2', '1','4','4','3','5','2')))
```

I have working code that allows me to run a regression model for multiple DVs (which I'm sure more experienced R users will dislike for its lack of efficiency):

```
y <- as.matrix(df[4:6])
#model for age
lm_results <- lm(y ~ age, data = df)

write.csv((broom::tidy(lm_results)), "lm_results_age.csv")

regression_results <-broom::tidy(lm_results)
standardized_coefficients <- lm.beta(lm_results)
age_standardize_results <- coef(standardized_coefficients)

write.csv(age_standardize_results, "lm_results_age_standardized_coefficients.csv")
```

I would then repeat this all by manually replacing  `age` with `sex` and `education`

Does anyone have a more elegant way of running this - for example, by way of a loop for all IVs of interest (i.e. age, sex and education)?

Also would greatly appreciate anyone who would suggest a quick way of combining `broom::tidy(lm_results)` with standardized coefficients from `lm.beta::lm.beta`, i.e. combining the standardized regression coefficients with the main model output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an adaptation for a similar workflow I had to use in the past. Remember to really penalize yourself for running a crazy number of models. I added a couple predictor columns to your dataframe. Good luck!!

**Solution**:

```
# Creating pedictor and outcome vectors
ivs_vec <- names(df)[c(2:6, 10)]
dvs_vec <- names(df)[7:9]

# Creating formulas and running the models
ivs <- paste0(" ~ ", ivs_vec)
dvs_ivs <- unlist(lapply(ivs, function(x) paste0(dvs_vec, x)))
formulas <- lapply(dvs_ivs, formula)

lm_results <- lapply(formulas, function(x) {
  lm(x, data = df)
})

# Creating / combining results
tidy_results <- lapply(lm_results, broom::tidy)
dv_list <- lapply(as.list(stringi::stri_extract_first_words(dvs_ivs)), rep, 2)
tidy_results <- Map(cbind, dv_list, tidy_results)

standardized_results <- lapply(lm_results, function(x) coef(lm.beta::lm.beta(x)))
combined_results <- Map(cbind, tidy_results, standardized_results)

# Cleaning up final results
names(combined_results) <- dvs_ivs
combined_results <- lapply(combined_results, function(x) {row.names(x) <- c(NULL); x})

new_names <- c("Outcome", "Term", "Estimate", "Std. Error", "Statistic", "P-value", "Standardized Estimate")
combined_results <- lapply(combined_results, setNames, new_names)
```

**Results**:

```
combined_results[1:5]

$`testscore_1 ~ age`
  Outcome        Term    Estimate Std. Error Statistic   P-value 
Standardized Estimate
1 testscore_1 (Intercept) 18.06027731 12.3493569 1.4624468 0.1776424            0.00000000
2 testscore_1         age  0.05835152  0.2031295 0.2872627 0.7804155            0.09531823

$`testscore_2 ~ age`
      Outcome        Term   Estimate Std. Error Statistic   P-value Standardized Estimate
1 testscore_2 (Intercept) 3.63788676 4.39014570 0.8286483 0.4287311             0.0000000
2 testscore_2         age 0.01367313 0.07221171 0.1893478 0.8540216             0.0629906

$`testscore_3 ~ age`
      Outcome        Term  Estimate Std. Error Statistic   P-value Standardized Estimate
1 testscore_3 (Intercept) 6.1215175   6.698083 0.9139208 0.3845886             0.0000000
2 testscore_3         age 0.1943125   0.110174 1.7636870 0.1116119             0.5068026

$`testscore_1 ~ sex`
      Outcome        Term Estimate Std. Error  Statistic      P-value Standardized Estimate
1 testscore_1 (Intercept)     22.5   3.099283  7.2597435 4.766069e-05             0.0000000
2 testscore_1         sex     -2.1   4.596980 -0.4568217 6.586248e-01            -0.1505386

$`testscore_2 ~ sex`
      Outcome        Term Estimate Std. Error Statistic     P-value Standardized Estimate
1 testscore_2 (Intercept) 3.666667   1.041129  3.521816 0.006496884             0.0000000
2 testscore_2         sex 1.733333   1.544245  1.122447 0.290723029             0.3504247
```

**Data**:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006,1007, 1008, 1009,   1010, 1011),
                     age = as.numeric(c('56', '43','59','74','61','62','69','80','40','55','58')),
                     sex = as.numeric(c('0','1','0','0','1','1','0','1','0','1','0')),
                     pred1 = sample(1:11, 11),
                     pred2 = sample(1:11, 11),
                     pred3 = sample(1:11, 11),
                     testscore_1 = as.numeric(c('23','28','30','15','7','18','29','27','14','22','24')),
                     testscore_2 = as.numeric(c('1','3','2','5','8','2','5','6','7','8','2')),
                     testscore_3 = as.numeric(c('18','20','19','15','20','23','19','25','10','14','12')),
                     education =  as.numeric(c('5','4','3','5','2', '1','4','4','3','5','2')))
```

Comment: This is so useful!! Thanks @Andrew!

Comment: So I've now added covariates (which are the same across all models): ```ivs_vec <- names(df)[c(2:3, 10)];
dvs_vec <- names(df)[7:9]; covs_vec <- paste("pred1", "+", "pred2", "+", "pred3"); ivs_covs <- paste0(" ~ ", ivs_vec, " + ", covs_vec); dvs_ivs_covs <- unlist(lapply(ivs_covs, function(x) paste0(dvs_vec, x)))```. I was just wondering how you would save the results of ```combined_results```as a csv, such that the results of all regression models are printed one after the other (i.e. in one long column - similar to 
```write.csv((broom::tidy(lm_results)), "lm_results_age.csv")```?

Comment: I'm almost there! I've used the following: ```library(data.table);
lstData <- Map(as.data.frame, combined_results);
dfrData <- rbindlist(lstData);
combined_results_dataframe <- rbindlist(lstData); write.csv(combined_results_dataframe, "combined_results.csv")```. Just need a column reflecting dependent variables now. Could you please let me know if you have any suggestions @Andrew?

Comment: I am glad it is helpful!! Hmm, so what exactly do you mean by a column of DVs. You could extract the dv from the `dvs_ivs_covs` vector using regex. If your regression table is 3 lines, do you want the dv name to repeat three times? Or, how do you want it to look? If that's what yo want, I'll post an edit!

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank you for the quick reply! So you know how when you run a single regression model ```lm_results <- lm(testscore_1 ~ age, data = df)``` and you tidy it up via ```(broom::tidy(lm_results)``` you get a "response" column followed by "term", "estimate","standard error" ect.. That's what I'm hoping to have! So yes - a dv name to repeat three times if we've run three seperate regressions! Ideally, I'd hope to implement this before this step :```combined_results <- Map(cbind, tidy_results, standardized_results)``` if that's feasible! I really appreciate your help on this :)!

Comment: Hmm, I do not get a "response" column. So, you want the name of the dv to be its own column with the name of the dv repeated on the intercept line, IV-1 line, and IV-2, line (for example)? That is definitely do-able I just wanted to clarify what you wanted.

Comment: Oh interesting! I wonder why that is. Ideally, a new column for dependent variables that repeat across all lines of a model (e.g. intercept line, age, and co-variates). This will be really useful for the next stage when I've exported the file out of R.

Comment: Ok, then you can use something like this (below). This solution assumes the dv will always be one word and you'll have to adjust the rest of the script accordingly (e.g., use `Map` again to bind with with your tidy results. Add name in `new_names` vector. If this is what you are looking for I will edit the solution. Let me know!  `dv_list <- rep(stringi::stri_extract_first_words(dvs_ivs), sapply(tidy_results, nrow))` then `Map(cbind, dv_list, tidy_results)`

Comment: This works absolutely beautifully!!!! Thank you so much for all of your help, Andrew!

Comment: @M_Oxford, ok, I just updated it. I see where I went wrong. Let me know how that works!!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So ```dv_list <- lapply(as.list(stringi::stri_extract_first_words(dvs_ivs_covs)), rep, 2)
> tidy_results <- Map(cbind, dv_list, tidy_results)``` returns 
```Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 9```. However, when I change it to: ```... rep, 1);  tidy_results <- Map(cbind, dv_list, tidy_results)```. It seems to work totally fine and gives the results that I have found using my original code. What do you think?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I put in `2` because it my example I have two predictors. didn't that that through. It looks like it recycles the name of the dv so you can simplify it to `dv_list <- as.list(stringi::stri_extract_first_words(dvs_ivs))` and skip `lapply` and `rep`. Nice solution, @M_Oxford!

Comment: Couldn't have done it without your helps! Thanks again @Andrew. Have a lovely day!

Comment: Hi @Andrew, thanks again for all of your help with this earlier this year. I would like to credit you in my code, how would you prefer for me to do this?

Comment: @M_Oxford, thanks for reaching out but no worries about credit!! Feel free to link post if you want.

Comment: Ok @Andrew - will link post :)!

Comment: Hi again @Andrew! I was wondering whether you might have suggestions for another questions I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60668630/comparing-multiple-aucs-in-parallel-r
It's based on your code from this answer. Would really appreciate your advice if you have time! :)

Comment: I will definitely check it out later today / this weekend if nobody gets to it!!

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon this a year later and documenting a `tidyverse` solution same data as @Andrew.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

# Creating pedictor and outcome vectors
ivs_vec <- names(df)[c(2:6, 10)]
dvs_vec <- names(df)[7:9]

# Creating formulas and running the models
ivs <- paste0(" ~ ", ivs_vec)
dvs_ivs <- unlist(map(ivs, ~paste0(dvs_vec, .x)))

models <- map(setNames(dvs_ivs, dvs_ivs),
              ~ lm(formula = as.formula(.x),
                   data = df))

basics <-
   map(models, ~ broom::tidy(.)) %>%
   map2_df(.,
           names(.),
           ~ mutate(.x, which_dependent = .y)) %>%
   select(which_dependent, everything()) %>%
   mutate(term = gsub("\\(Intercept\\)", "Intercept", term),
          which_dependent = stringi::stri_extract_first_words(which_dependent))

basics$std_estimate <-
   map_dfr(models, ~ coef(lm.beta::lm.beta(.)), .id = "which_dependent") %>%
   pivot_longer(.,
                cols = -which_dependent,
                names_to = "term",
                values_to = "std_estimate",
                values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
   pull(std_estimate)

basics
#> # A tibble: 36 x 7
#>    which_dependent term      estimate std.error statistic   p.value std_estimate
#>    <chr>           <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>
#>  1 testscore_1     Intercept  18.1      12.3        1.46  0.178           0     
#>  2 testscore_1     age         0.0584    0.203      0.287 0.780           0.0953
#>  3 testscore_2     Intercept   3.64      4.39       0.829 0.429           0     
#>  4 testscore_2     age         0.0137    0.0722     0.189 0.854           0.0630
#>  5 testscore_3     Intercept   6.12      6.70       0.914 0.385           0     
#>  6 testscore_3     age         0.194     0.110      1.76  0.112           0.507 
#>  7 testscore_1     Intercept  22.5       3.10       7.26  0.0000477       0     
#>  8 testscore_1     sex        -2.10      4.60      -0.457 0.659          -0.151 
#>  9 testscore_2     Intercept   3.67      1.04       3.52  0.00650         0     
#> 10 testscore_2     sex         1.73      1.54       1.12  0.291           0.350 
#> # … with 26 more rows
```