# Comparing multiple AUCs in parallel (R)

Tags: r, function, loops, auc

I am using the pROC package in r to calculate and compare the AUCs of multiple tests, to see which test has the best ability to discriminate between patients and controls. However, I have a large number of tests and essentially want to run a series of pairwise comparisons of each tests AUC with every other test and then correct for multiple comparisons. This is as far as I've gotten with my code (example with simulated and replicable dataset below):

```
#load pROC
library(pROC)

#generate df with random numbers
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(disease_status = rbinom(n=100, size=1, prob=0.20),
                 test1 = rnorm(100, mean=15, sd=4),
                 test2 = rnorm(100, mean=30, sd=2),
                 test3 = rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=3))

#create roc object for test1, test2, test3
roc.out_test1<-roc(df$disease_status, df$test1, plot=TRUE, smooth = FALSE)
roc.out_test2<-roc(df$disease_status, df$test2, plot=TRUE, smooth = FALSE)
roc.out_test3<-roc(df$disease_status, df$test3, plot=TRUE, smooth = FALSE)

#compare the AUC of test1 and test 2
roc.test(roc.out_test1, roc.out_test2, reuse.auc=TRUE, method="delong", na.rm=TRUE)

#DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves
#data:  roc.out_test1 and roc.out_test2
#Z = 0.60071, p-value = 0.548
#alternative hypothesis: true difference in AUC is not equal to 0
#sample estimates:
#AUC of roc1 AUC of roc2 
#0.5840108   0.5216802 

#create a function to do above for all comparisons
vec_ROCs1 <- c("roc.out_test1,", "roc.out_test2,", "roc.out_test3,")
vec_ROCs2 <- c("roc.out_test1", "roc.out_test2", "roc.out_test3")
ROCs2_specifications  <- paste0(vec_ROCs2, ",", "reuse.auc=TRUE")
test <- unlist(lapply(ROCs2_specifications, function(x) paste0(vec_ROCs1, x)))
test2 <- lapply(test, function(x) roc.test(x))

#Error in roc.test.default(x) : 
#  argument "predictor1" is missing, with no default
```

Please let me know your thoughts and suggestions on how to fix this!

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a minimal example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Thanks @agila! It's updated with a reproducible example now.

Comment: The problem here is the list `test` is just a list of characters and the function `roc.test()` expects ROC objects as inputs. You need to create a list of those objects to iterate over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, please check it. I didn't write all the details, but you can ask me other questions if you don't understand the code.

```r
#load pROC
library(pROC)
#> Type 'citation("pROC")' for a citation.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pROC'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     cov, smooth, var

#generate df with random numbers
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(disease_status = rbinom(n=100, size=1, prob=0.20),
                 test1 = rnorm(100, mean=15, sd=4),
                 test2 = rnorm(100, mean=30, sd=2),
                 test3 = rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=3))

#create roc object for test1, test2, test3
roc.out_test1<-roc(df$disease_status, df$test1, plot=TRUE, smooth = FALSE)
#> Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#> Setting direction: controls < cases

roc.out_test2<-roc(df$disease_status, df$test2, plot=TRUE, smooth = FALSE)
#> Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#> Setting direction: controls < cases

roc.out_test3<-roc(df$disease_status, df$test3, plot=TRUE, smooth = FALSE)
#> Setting levels: control = 0, case = 1
#> Setting direction: controls < cases

# compare the AUC of test1 and test 2
roc.test(roc.out_test1, roc.out_test2, reuse.auc = TRUE, method = "delong", na.rm = TRUE)
#> 
#>  DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves
#> 
#> data:  roc.out_test1 and roc.out_test2
#> Z = 0.60071, p-value = 0.548
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in AUC is not equal to 0
#> sample estimates:
#> AUC of roc1 AUC of roc2 
#>   0.5840108   0.5216802
```

Now we generate a list of all possible combinations of the three tests and run the `roc.test` function using the same parameters that you set.

```r
all_tests <- combn(
  list(
    "test1" = roc.out_test1,
    "test2" = roc.out_test2,
    "test3" = roc.out_test3
  ),
  FUN = function(x, ...) roc.test(x[[1]], x[[2]]),
  m = 2,
  simplify = FALSE, 
  reuse.auc = TRUE, 
  method = "delong", 
  na.rm = TRUE
)
```

The output is a list of `choose(3, 2) = 3` elements (i.e. the number of combinations of n elements taken 2 at a time) and each element of the list is a test. For example this is the same as your previous test:

```r
all_tests[[1]]
#> 
#>  DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves
#> 
#> data:  x[[1]] and x[[2]]
#> Z = 0.60071, p-value = 0.548
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in AUC is not equal to 0
#> sample estimates:
#> AUC of roc1 AUC of roc2 
#>   0.5840108   0.5216802
```

The only problem here is that it's difficult to recognise which tests are used in the comparisons, so we can also add a list of names:

```r
tests_names <- combn(
  list("test1", "test2", "test3"), 
  m = 2, 
  FUN = paste, 
  simplify = TRUE, 
  collapse = "_"
)
all_tests <- setNames(all_tests, tests_names)
```

This is the result.

```r
names(all_tests)
#> [1] "test1_test2" "test1_test3" "test2_test3"
```

The names of the objects flag the tests that are used in the comparison.

```r
all_tests$test1_test2
#> 
#>  DeLong's test for two correlated ROC curves
#> 
#> data:  x[[1]] and x[[2]]
#> Z = 0.60071, p-value = 0.548
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in AUC is not equal to 0
#> sample estimates:
#> AUC of roc1 AUC of roc2 
#>   0.5840108   0.5216802
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: would yourecommend to do pvalue correction for multiple comparisons?

Comment: I'm not sure about the details in your specific situation, but usually yes, you need to apply some sort of correction for multiple testing.

Comment: thank you for the response! yes, i was talking about the example provided here: we basically do the pairwise comparisons here- so usually I would apply BH or bonferonni correction to adjust for multiple testing

Answer (score 1):

The roc.test() function expects a roc object as input. The list `test` is just character strings of all the arguments, which the function does not know what to do with. The list also includes comparisons of the tests with themselves i.e. "roc.out_test1,roc.out_test1,reuse.auc=TRUE" I assume you don't actually need to do this and that there are only 3 comparisons that you need 1v2, 1v3, 2v3. The `purrr` package provides `map` functions similar to `lapply` and `map2` allows you to iterate of 2 lists at the same time. You need to create 2 lists of the actually roc objects and iterate over these.

```
#load pROC
library(pROC)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) #For map2 function

#generate df with random numbers
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(disease_status = rbinom(n=100, size=1, prob=0.20),
                 test1 = rnorm(100, mean=15, sd=4),
                 test2 = rnorm(100, mean=30, sd=2),
                 test3 = rnorm(100, mean=50, sd=3))

#create roc object for test1, test2, test3
roc.out_test1<-roc(df$disease_status, df$test1, plot=TRUE, smooth = FALSE)
roc.out_test2<-roc(df$disease_status, df$test2, plot=TRUE, smooth = FALSE)
roc.out_test3<-roc(df$disease_status, df$test3, plot=TRUE, smooth = FALSE)

#compare the AUC of test1 and test 2
roc.test(roc.out_test1, roc.out_test2, reuse.auc=TRUE, method="delong", na.rm=TRUE)

roc_new <- function(test1,  test2){
  roc.test(test1, test2, reuse.auc=TRUE, method="delong", na.rm=TRUE)
}

#List of all tests
all_tests <- list(roc.out_test1,
                  roc.out_test2,
                  roc.out_test3) 

#Create unique combos of tests
unique_combos <- expand.grid(1:3, 1:3) %>% 
  filter(Var1 < Var2) %>% #exludes duplicate comparisons, 
                      #each col provides the index for the 2 lists to iterate over
  mutate(names = paste(Var1, " V ",  Var2)) #Create col to name final output list


#Create 2 lists to iterate over
#Create list 1
(test1 <- all_tests[as.numeric(unique_combos$Var1)])
#Create list 2
(test2 <- all_tests[as.numeric(unique_combos$Var2)])

#Iterate over both lists
output <- map2(test1, test2, roc_new)
names(output) <- unique_combos$names
```